# Create a list of custom objects with Inversion of Control paradigm

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, abstraction

I want to adapt Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control into my daily development. Say I have an object type of `SomeObject` (implements the interface `ISomeObject`). I have a class which consumes this object called Data which implements the `IData` interface.

```
public interface ISomeObject {
    int ID;
    string Name;
    bool IsAwesome;

    void DoSomeStuffIfAwesome();
}

public Class SomeObject : ISomeObject {
    int ID;
    string Name;
    bool IsAwesome;

    void DoSomeStuffIfAwesome() { /*stuff happens here*/ }        
}

public interface IData {
    List<ISomeObject> GetSomeObjects();
}

public Class Data : IData {
    List<ISomeObject> GetSomeObjects()
    {
        List<ISomeObject> objects = new List<ISomeObject>; // ??? Maybe and cast later?

        //do some SQL stuff and get a SqlDataReader object called reader
        while(reader.Read()) {
             //ISomeObject someObj = ???
             //Read into the someObj.ID, someObj.Name and someObj.IsAwesome fields
             objects.add(someObj);
        }
        return objects;
    }
}
```

The `GetSomeObjects()` method produces a list of `ISomeObject` objects. But I don't want `Data.cs` to have anything related to `SomeObject` hardcoded into it. I want some form of Dependency Injection to resolve the issue at runtime. What's the best way to handle this? I've considered the following:

**1. Pass instance of `SomeObject` into `Data`'s constructor.** This way I can get its type with `.GetType()`, store that into a private `System.Type` variable in `Data.cs`, and use `Activator.CreateInstance` in the loop to create new objects to be added to the list. `Data` would need to know about the `SomeObject` class specifically to cast, if I understand it correctly.

**2. Pass an instance of my IoC container to `Data`'s constructor** and just resolve the object type using `container.Resolve<ISomeObject>()`. This would make unit testing the `GetSomeObjects()` method difficult without utilizing my IoC container. I've read I shouldn't utilize the IoC container during unit testing, and should manually pass in what I need into methods.

**3. Pass an `ISomeObject` object that has been instantiated as a `SomeObject`** - I would then use that to create the object via some built in method, such as `SomeObject.GenerateList(IDataReader reader)`.

Comment: At some point a class has to be concrete. Why can't **that** implementation of `IData` know how to return a specific set of `ISomeObject` objects?

Comment: That could very well be the situation. My understanding was the the goal of IoC and Dependency Injection was to have the consumers only know about the Interface, and not the concrete class, so that I can swap out the concrete class quickly without needing to ever modify the consumer. So if I wanted to replace SomeObject in the future with another class that implements ISomeObject, I could do so without touching Data.cs. 

It could very well be that I have gone too deep into the idea of abstracting, and need to tone it back a bit. Perhaps I do need to instantiate SomeObject in Data.cs

Comment: Use a factory (`ISomeObjectFactory`) that takes the reader and returns a `ISomeObject`. Inject the factory into Data and the factory will know how to construct `ISomeObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delegate the creation of the object out to something else;

```
public interface ISomeObjectFactory {
    ISomeObject Create(IDataReader reader);
}
```

which has a single responsibility to create instances of `ISomeObject`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

public interface IDbConnectionFactory {
    ///<summary>
    ///  Creates a connection based on the given database name or connection string.
    ///</summary>
    IDbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString);
}

public class Data : IData {
    private IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory;
    ISomeObjectFactory someObjectFactory;
    private string CONNECTION_STRING = "Connection string here";

    public Data(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory, ISomeObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        this.dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
        this.someObjectFactory = objectFactory;
    }

    public List<ISomeObject> GetSomeObjects() {
        var objects = new List<ISomeObject>();
        //do some SQL stuff and return a data reader
        using (var connnection = dbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)) {
            using (var command = connnection.CreateCommand()) {
                //configure command to be executed.
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SOMEOBJECT_TABLE";
                connnection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        //...Logic to populate item
                        var someObject = someObjectFactory.Create(reader);
                        if (someObject != null)
                            objects.Add(someObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return objects;
    }
}
```

that way `Data` is only dependent on abstractions and not on concretions. Those can be determined/configured in the composition root at runtime.

Comment: This answer is great and should do the trick! Thank you very much =D